# Show the UIActivityViewController in own class

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiactivityviewcontroller

i am working on my app and want to share an image.
**First** i want to present the UIActivityViewController from my own class called **"PostCell"** (the class to handle my prototype-cell).
I get the message "Use of unresolved identifier 'present'"
(see the picture below). How can i call the vc correctly in my class?

**Second** i want to share **the actual image** which is in my postImageView: UIImageView! in the PostCell. Do i have to use IndexPath for the right image ?

Can you please help. THX a lot.

```
import UIKit
```

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

`@IBOutlet weak var postCaptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var stuffButton: UIButton!


@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let image = UIImage(self.postImageView.image) {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }

}...`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `UITableViewCell` does not have `present` method. That has to be done from the `ViewController` or create a reference in the cell to the `ViewController` and then call present. Second, `self.postImageView.image` will already give you a `UIImage` there is no need to construct it. Here is an example.

```
import UIKit


class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var postCaptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var stuffButton: UIButton!

// Here you add a reference to the viewController. Remember to write cell.viewController = self in the cellForRow method

var viewController : UIViewController!

@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Here you remove the UIImage constructor.
    if let image = self.postImageView.image {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
        viewController.present(vc, animated: true)
    }

}...
```